# cron jobs on amazon aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, cron

I am currently using amazon's elastic beanstalk as my web server. I need to be able to run some cron jobs every minute (so launching machines and shutting them down is not an option).

The solutions i have found for now are:

1. run an ec2 machine and run those cron's over there
2. use aws ops that is bit complicated to setup + will eventually run an ec2 machine anyways.

both of those solutions seems like an over kill. is there any better solution out there? the perfect solution would be a "Platform as a service" (PaaS) one.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, few years after. here are some new options to deal with this issue:

1. as Adam said, there is an option to set a recurring event in elastic beanstalks' configuration named "container commands".
   the behavior is as the following code:

   `container_commands:
   name of container_command:
   command: "command to run"
   leader_only: true
   name of container_command:
   command: "command to run"`

   reference: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#linux-container-commands
2. Second option is using the Lambda functions with schedule events - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-scheduled-events.html

hope this will help anyone that bumps into this issue

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it's possible to do it directly inside Beanstalk:

[AWS Elastic Beanstalk, running a cronjob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14077095/aws-elastic-beanstalk-running-a-cronjob)

If the endpoint to be run is external facing (to the web) you could check out Azure Scheduler:

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/scheduler/

Comment: I was hoping to use only amazon's set of tools, however, azure's service might be good for us. thanks

Comment: check this link as well : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11616205/run-scheduled-task-in-amazon-without-cron