# How to configure and run cronjob on AWS ElasticBeanStalk?

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, cron, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have deployed my laravel project on AWS Elasticbeanstalk and I have a cronjob task. How do I configure it to run? I have seen multiple answers but either they are no longer valid, too complex or not described well. Any sort of guide/steps I can follow to do that?

In many deployment services there's the cpanel where I would easily configure a cronjob but stating the path where it exists but I can't find anything for that on AWS.

Comment: possible duplicate of [AWS Elastic Beanstalk, running a cronjob](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14077095/aws-elastic-beanstalk-running-a-cronjob)

Comment: [Scheduled Tasks Without Cron](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11616205/run-scheduled-task-in-aws-without-cron) might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit late to post the answer but mainly you need to run `crontab -e` which would open a crontab file. You can then add all your jobs as follows:

`* * * * *  /path/to/your/command`

The 5 `*` means every minute forever so you need to configure it accordingly. You can check this [guide](http://crontab.org/) as well.

Comment: what if EBS scales down and terminate your configured instance?

Answer (score 1):

cpanel or even ssh access won't help you here, as Elastic Beanstalk is allowed to replace your server instances as it see fit. This means that if you use cpanel, your changes will be lost in the next time EB decides to spin up a new server.
Now in order to ensure your cron is properly populated, you'd need to use the *.ebextensions* mechanism. It's a small script that is run when a new server spins up, and can populate your cron.
Here're the steps to introduce such a script:

1. create a /.ebextensions folder in the root of your project
2. create the file /.ebextension/populate_cron.config
3. enter the following text into that file:

`container_commands:
  populate_cron:
    command: crontab -l | { cat; echo "0 0 0 0 0 your command"; } | crontab -
    leader_only: true`

*(note that this is a yaml file, so keep the indentation as is)*

4. commit this file and `eb deploy`
5. after the env is up, `eb ssh` to see that the cron is there

Comment: What to do if it's not there when ssh'ing?

Comment: leader_only will only help for commands during provisioning. The leader can (and is) scaled in ... aka. terminated ... without been replaced!