# How to run a query for every date for last 3 month

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, cron, amazon-redshift

I have a table(pkg_date) in redshift. I want to fetch some data for every date for the last 3 months.

Here is my query

```
select * from pkg_data where scan_date < current_date;
```

How can I use current_date as a variable in the query itself and run this query for every date from April 1.

I have set a cron job which will run in every hour. In every hour it should run with different current_date

Comment: `In every hour it should run with different current_date` Which date do you want to be used at which time_of_execution? is there some kind of formula?

Answer (score 1):

Use [dateadd()](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_DATEADD_function.html) for getting date 3 moth old day and [GETDATE()](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_DATEADD_function.html) for get current date.

ie code will look like.

```
select * from pkg_data where scan_date < dateadd(month,-3,GETDATE());
```

for cron refer [How to execute scheduled SQL script on Amazon Redshift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42564910/how-to-execute-scheduled-sql-script-on-amazon-redshift)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM pkg_data
WHERE scan_date > CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '3 months'
```

Be careful — Redshift works in UTC, so the *CURRENT_DATE* might suffer from timezone effects and be +/- what you expect sometimes.

```
SELECT
  CURRENT_DATE,
  (CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '3 months')::date
```

Returns:

```
2018-06-21  2018-03-21
```

Also be careful with strange lengths of months!

```
SELECT DATE '2018-05-31' - INTERVAL '3 months'
```

returns:

```
2018-02-28 00:00:00
```

Notice that it gave the last day of the month (31st vs 28th).

By the way, you can use `DATE '2018-05-31'` or `'2018-05-31'::DATE`, and also `INTERVAL '3 months'` or `'3 months'::INTERVAL` to convert types.