# How to schedule a daily backup of DDL definition view (pg_catalog table) in Redshift

Tags: backup, amazon-redshift

We generate a lot of DDL views.I want to create a back-up of all the DDL views in the pg_catalog or information_schema which updates it self everyday.

For example: 
If the number of views yesterday was 10 and I created 5 more views today, the backup table should update itself from 10 to 15 at a specific time.

Comment: Are you using any ETL tool or any frame work to load data run/schedule jobs? Create a simple insert into a `DDL_History` table Sql and schedule it.

Comment: Hi Its just a simple table which i want to keep a back up of. So the back up table will take data from the existing table. I want it to do it daily.  No ETL tool or anything. Can you provide an example?

Comment: Creating the SQL to move data from one table to another is easy. You need have a scheduler to run that SQL daily because you can not schedule this in Redshift or any other database. It could be a Lambda function, cron job, a simple python script etc. This is the part you need to decide what to use.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a scheduled lambda function that queries to find the number of views, then updates the backup table based on that query. Documentation for how to connect to a Redshift cluster from a lambda function can be found [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/connecting-in-code.html).

Comment: Hi,i want to do it using a sql query

Comment: Unfortunately there's no way to have a scheduled query with Redshift on its own... You will likely want to create a lambda to perform this query for you daily. This is of course assuming you don't want to perform the query manually every day :) You can find more here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42564910/how-to-execute-scheduled-sql-script-on-amazon-redshift