# Can I publish to SQS in scheduled Amazon CloudWatch Event?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-sqs, amazon-cloudwatch

The answer to this post states that **Amazon Simple Notification Service** (SNS) topic can be triggered by **Amazon CloudWatch Events** schedule without utilizing an **AWS Lambda** function:

[Scheduled rest requests from aws](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43706034/scheduled-rest-requests-from-aws)

Is there an ability to automatically publish to SQS when a scheduled **Amazon CloudWatch Event** occurs without using lambda? Can I set this up by means of Cloud Formation template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This functionality is supported.

See: https://aws.amazon.com/ru/about-aws/whats-new/2016/03/cloudwatch-events-now-supports-amazon-sqs-queue-targets/

The example of Cloud Formation template:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/52029876/4251336