# Execute Lambda function based on threshold

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

I have created a Lambda function which will be triggered via a subscription to a CloudWatch Log Pattern and the function will in-turn pass the logs to a web-hook (Refer https://gist.github.com/tomfa/f4e090cbaff0189eba17c0fc301c63db).

Now, I need this lambda function to EXECUTE only if the the function is called "x" times in "y" minutes.

Is it possible to disable/enable a lambda through SNS. Another idea is to
1. Create CloudWatch Events on State Change
2. Subscribe this to a SNS which will 
enables the lambda, if state goes from OK to ALARM
disables the lambda, if state goes back to OK

Answer (score 1):

You can use CloudWatch Events to send a message to an Amazon SNS topic on a schedule. make sure you are in correct region as as CloudWatch Events is not available in every region.

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/WhatIsCloudWatchEvents.html

How to configure Cloudwatch :

- [AWS Lambda Scheduled Tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27382009/aws-lambda-scheduled-tasks)
- [run scheduled task in AWS without cron](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11616205/run-scheduled-task-in-aws-without-cron)
- [AWS Lambda Scheduled Tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27382009/aws-lambda-scheduled-tasks)

Use CloudWatch and get metrics about the lambda invocation and error and you can find successful call and error , threshold count. now you can use AWS SDK

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudwatch/get-metric-data.html

```
export.handler = function(event, context, callback) {
  apiCall().then(resp => callback(null, resp).catch(err => callback(err));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a custom CloudWatch Metric based of your search filter of the CloudWatch Logs

Examples of this can be found in the Amazon CloudWatch Logs User Guide

1. [Count Log Events](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/CountingLogEventsExample.html)

```
aws logs put-metric-filter \
  --log-group-name MyApp/access.log \
  --filter-name EventCount \
  --filter-pattern "" \
  --metric-transformations \
  metricName=MyAppEventCount,metricNamespace=MyNamespace,metricValue=1,defaultValue=0
```

2. [Count Occurrences](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/CountOccurrencesExample.html)

```
aws logs put-metric-filter \
  --log-group-name MyApp/message.log \
  --filter-name MyAppErrorCount \
  --filter-pattern 'Error' \
  --metric-transformations \
      metricName=ErrorCount,metricNamespace=MyNamespace,metricValue=1,defaultValue=0
```

Then you can go in and create a CloudWatch Alarm that will fire based on x of these events being logged in y time span. The CloudWatch Alarm can send a message to an SNS topic that triggers your Lambda function