# Alternate to cron in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, cron

We are monitoring Abinitio and Informatica services(which are running in EC2) using scripts and publishing into cloud watch which are scheduled using cronjob. How would I avoid using cron and have AWS native service or any other solution possible?

Comment: If you are wanting to trigger something on an Amazon EC2 instance, then you need something that can run on the instance itself (rather than externally). Therefore, `cron` is a good choice. Why do you wish to find an alternative option? The only one I can think of is using EventBridge to schedule an AWS Systems Manager Run Command that will execute code on one or more Amazon EC2 instances.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [run scheduled task in AWS without cron](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11616205/run-scheduled-task-in-aws-without-cron)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand your question, you’re effectively emitting metrics using scripts invoked as cron jobs, correct?

If so, then there is no alternative option to my knowledge, if you’re emitting your metrics to CloudWatch. CloudWatch doesn’t pull your metrics, it’s you who have to send them. Some other systems might be able to pull metrics, like Prometheus though.